# Eigenvalue of endomorphism is zero of corresponding minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space and $f\colon V\to V$ some endomorphism.

Show: If $m_f(X)\in K[X]$ is the minimal polynomial of $f$ and $\lambda\in K$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, then $m_f(\lambda)=0$.

---

Here is what I tried as a proof:

Let $\lambda\in K$ be an eigenvalue of $f$, i.e. there exists $v\in V, v\neq 0$, such that $f(v)=\lambda v$. Then, by polynomial division, there exist $p, r\in K[X]$ such that
$$
m_f(X)=p(X)(X-\lambda)+r(X)
$$
where $\textrm{deg}(r)=0$, i.e., $r=c$ für some constant $c\in K$.

Then, since $m_f(f)=0$,

$$
0=m_f(f)=p(f)(f-\lambda)+r(f).
$$
Thus, mapping $v$,
$$
0 = (p(f))(v)\cdot(f-\lambda)(v)+(r(f))(v)=p(\lambda)v\cdot\underbrace{(f(v)-\lambda v)}_{=\lambda v-\lambda v=0}+cv=cv
$$

Since $v\neq 0$, it follows that $r=0$.

Consequently,
$$
m_f(X)=p(X)(X-\lambda),
$$
meaning that $m_f(\lambda)=0$.

Would like to know if my proof is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat simpler: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ a corresponding eigenvector,
so $f (v) = \lambda v$, then also $f^k(v) = \lambda^k v$ for nonnegative integers $k$.
By linearity, for any polynomial $P$, $P(f) v = P(\lambda) v$, and in particular $0 = m_f(f) v = m_f(\lambda) v$, so $m_f(\lambda) = 0$.